# Is it possible to fix an argument to a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to put a variable number of arguments into a buffer, and so I've overloaded the `<<` operator to insert values into given buffer:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void pack(T first, Args... args, std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer) {
    pack(args ..., buffer);
    buffer << first;
} 

void pack(std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer) { return; }
```

Since variadic template functions rely on recursion, my idea is to have a base case that returns the buffer and a recursive case that inserts the first argument into the buffer (after the recursive call).

However, if I run code like:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
pack((uint8_t)0xFF, (uint32_t)0x0A, buffer);
hex_dump(buffer);
```

I get an error message saying:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
./misc.hpp:20:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class ... Args> void pack(T, Args ..., std::vector<unsigned char>&)
 void pack(T first, Args... args, std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer);
      ^~~~
./misc.hpp:20:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:35:47: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
     pack((uint8_t)0xFF, (uint32_t)0x0A, buffer);
```

How can I pass the buffer in the recursive case, so that I can append the value to partially filled buffer?

Comment: May variadic only be last argument?

Comment: leave the variadic as the last argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler would be to have your buffer at first argument:

```
void pack(std::vector<uint8_t> &) {}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void pack(std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer, T first, Args... args) {
    buffer << first;
    pack(buffer, args ...);
}
```

And in C++17, with Fold expression, you may directly write:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void pack(std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer, Args... args) {
    (buffer << ... << args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, your solution gives the error "/tmp/ccNl3d0x.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `void pack<unsigned char, unsigned int>(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, unsigned char, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". Any idea?

Comment: Where have you defined the template ? in a cpp (which is not where you use it ) ?

Comment: I've the declared the template in a .hpp file which I include, but defined the template in a .cpp file - isn't this correct?

Comment: I see that it works, if I take the template definition into the main.cpp file - but I don't want to define in every file, where I use this template?

Comment: Look at [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: thanks, I didn't knew this. I don't think that is elegant, but if that's the only way of doing it...

Comment: @Shuzheng you could upvote and/or accept this answer instead of just saying "thanks".

Comment: @Jarod42 - is my solution of putting `inline` before both template definitions in the header file the correct solution? Your link mostly talk about template classes, and doesn't really mention much about the use of `inline`.

Comment: template definitions are implicitly `inline`, so you can omit `inline` for template definitions.